# Filtering forwarded traffic on the physical interface when using a bridge

Tags: centos, networking, iptables

My setup has me with a bridge that sits on two physical interfaces

```
[root@CentOS8-Middle ~]# nmcli c s 
NAME       UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
br0        6bb79a71-235e-4c1b-b1bb-33262214144b  bridge    br0    
vbr0-port1  bf6b5b16-0e64-4802-928f-534564203af3  ethernet  ens224 
vbr0-port2  251016a7-38e7-4390-a69a-8a91c37c64db  ethernet  ens256 
ens192     573ba4c1-1c97-4704-ba36-c75a69635e8e  ethernet  ens192 
[root@CentOS8-Middle ~]#
```

I able to filter traffic in iptalbes send it to the nfq filter by doing

```
-A FORWARD -i br0 -p icmp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 --queue-bypass
```

However I would like to filter based on the physical interface that the traffic is coming in on. I tried the lines below:

```
iotables -I FORWARD -i ens256 -p icmp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 --queue-bypass
iptables -I INBOUND -i ens256 -p icmp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 --queue-bypass
iptables -I OUTBOUND -i ens256 -p icmp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 --queue-bypass
```

and every time when I run

```
iptables -L -nv
```

I see all traffic on the FORWARD chain. Is it possible to do this way? If not do I need to have iptalbles to the forwarding (and not NetworkManager)?

Answer (score 0):

The rules below seems to address my concern.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged  --physdev-in ens256 --physdev-out ens224 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 --queue-bypass
iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged  --physdev-in ens224 --physdev-out ens256 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2 --queue-bypass
```

Comment: Once you use physdev, because it requires it, [br_netfilter is loaded](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html). You now become subject to iptables receiving twice the traffic: once for the bridged frame ("upgraded" to an ip packet) and once for the routed packet. See details [there](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html), especially this chapter: [7. Two possible ways for frames/packets to pass through the iptables PREROUTING, FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7). So be careful with your rules now.